# how do I strip text to discard file location and leave only file name

Tags: php, mysql

I am learning `PHP` & `MySQL`.  Thanks to this great site and some other resources I have learned how to read through a database of mp3s

My goal is to identify songs without lyrics and make a copy of each song in another folder.  `$row['filename']` returns the full location such as `"C:/../../../nameOfArtist/nameOfAlbum/foo.mp3"`  I do not know how to take that and move just the song into another directory creating an artist sub-directory and album sub-directory in the process.

Something like `copy(($row['filename']), (C:/foo . '$row['artist'] . $row['album'] . "foo.mp3");`

Here is what I have so far that works

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, artist, title, album, filename 
             FROM songlist 
                         WHERE lyrics IS NULL or lyrics = '' ");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "Artist: " . $row['artist']  . "     Title: " . $row['title'] . "     Album: " . $row['album'] . "<br/>;

$filename = $row['filename'];
echo $filename . "<br/>";
```

Comment: Are you expecting MySQL to do a file copy?

Comment: You are missing a closing `"` on your first `echo`

Comment: `how do I strip text to discard file location and leave only file name` http://www.php.net/basename

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php - Copy() - Copies file

http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php - Basename() - Returns trailing name component of path

```
$filename = $row['filename'];
copy ( $filename , "C:\\foo\\" . basename($filename) );
```

Comment: David thank you so much..  I tried this and I get the following error "Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => copy(D:\RadioMetaverse\Artists in database\Billy Joel\The Complete Hits Collection 1973-1997- Limited Edition Disc 1\02 Captain Jack.mp3): failed to open stream: Permission denied [file] => C:\Program Files\Windows Server\Bin\WebApps\Site\html5\noLyrics.php [line] => 37 ) "  of course line 37 is copy ( $filename , "C:\\foo\\" . basename($filename) ); but I think it is a windows permission thing. does not let the IIS7 or something write to the foo folder.  I did create a foo folder )

Comment: The "foo" was just example, you can, of  course, copy it anywhere. But you need to tell windows to allow access: http://forums.iis.net/t/1167645.aspx and http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/windows-7-access-denied-permission-ownership/